# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'category' RSS

Tags: python3

NEWS情報をDiscordで出したいのですがErrorが出ます

`AttributeError: object has no attribute 'category'`

```
if message.content.startswith('/news'):
    RSS_URL = "https://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/rss/all-c_ent.xml"
    yahoo_news_dic = feedparser.parse(RSS_URL)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, yahoo_news_dic.feed.title)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, yahoo_news_dic.feed.link)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, yahoo_news_dic.feed.category)
```

Comment: RSSのデータに該当のものがないためと思われます。データを確認してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

パースしているRSSの `<channel>` タグ以下には `<category>` タグが無いようです。
存在しない辞書のキーや属性にアクセスすると例外が発生します。
この例外をキャッチして処理するか、例外が発生しない方法でアクセスする必要があります。

[`in`](https://docs.python.jp/3/reference/expressions.html#in) でチェックする例:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import feedparser
RSS_URL = "https://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/rss/all-c_ent.xml"
yahoo_news_dic = feedparser.parse(RSS_URL)

if "category" in yahoo_news_dic.feed:
    print("カテゴリ:", yahoo_news_dic.feed["category"])
```

---

[`get`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get) でデフォルト値を指定する例:

```
print("カテゴリ:", yahoo_news_dic.feed.get("category", "不明"))
```